# Huskies are a compact?

Tags: ambiguity

There is an article about huskies. It says:

> Siberian huskies are among the most beautiful of dogs. They are a **compact** but strong-looking dog with a neat coat and a large bushy tail that is usually held erect.

What does **compact** mean here? I have looked it up on ODLA but there is nothing suitable:

- 1 (North American English) a small car
- 2 a small flat box with a mirror, containing powder that women use on
  their faces
- 3 (formal) a formal agreement between two or more people or countries
  The government has signed a compact of free association.

Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 9th edition © Oxford University Press, 2015

Comment: Look at the [adjective form](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/compact)

Comment: McCawley's 'The Syntactic Phenomena of English' is an expensive but useful book.

Comment: "They are a compact...dog": 'compact' is an adjective here, not a noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Dictionary.com, "compact" has the following meanings:

> 1. joined or packed together; closely and firmly united; dense; solid:
>      as in "compact soil."
> 2. arranged within a relatively small space: a compact shopping center; 
>      as in "a compact kitchen."
> 3. designed to be small in size and economical in operation.
> 4. solidly or firmly built:

The meaning here is referring to their size to power ratio.  So in this context, the author is saying the Huskie is "designed to be small in size, economical in operation and solidly built."

In other words, Huskies are not a large breed of dog but have great strength for their size.

**EDIT**

AndyT is correct.  The word compact can be used as both a noun and an adjective.  The definition you listed from  Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary is the definition of the noun, while the one I provided was for the word used as an adjective (it modifies dog.)

Comment: You've failed to explain the part the OP is most struggling with, i.e. it's not a *noun*, it's an *adjective* describing the noun "dog".

Answer (score -1):

Ectomorphic means a build with little fat or muscle but with long limbs. Examples would be Greyhounds.

Endomorphic means have a squat, fleshy build. Such as Pugs & Bulldogs.

Mesomorphic is having a robust, muscular body build. Big boned and lots of muscles such as a Pit bull.

IMHO a huskie being a compact dog would fall into a morphological category mesomorph. More here  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_anatomy#Physical_characteristics) and here [Am Kennel Club](http://www.akc.org/search/bWVzb21vcnBoaWM/)

Comment: How does this answer the question "What does *compact* mean here?"?